# HP Device Manager still in menu after HPLIP uninstall

Tags: xubuntu, hplip

I have uninstalled HPLIP according to the directions on http://hplipopensource.com/node/188 from Xubuntu 14.04, meaning that I typed this into my terminal emulator:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/hplip
sudo rm -rf /etc/hp
sudo rm -rf ~/.hplip
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/hp
```

Those commands removed everything, but a shortcut to HP Device Manager is still in my menu. Of course, when I click it it says it can't find the executable but that's normal because it's a shortcut. So, is this a bug or did I do something wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: I am unsure you followed the directions completely, you were supposed to make an uninstall from the tarball. Then do those commands afterwards. You could try installing it again, or fixing/repairing, then go through the uninstall again. If possible you can try this guide too: http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/hplip/ As it is all you did was remove the files

Comment: I see. I need to use `sudo make uninstall`, but I don't know where my source tarball is. I think I will try reinstalling HPLIP then looking for the directory and uninstalling it that way. I will let you know how that works out.

Comment: I uninstalled hplip (by deleting the files shown above and uninstalling the hplip package using Synaptic) but my networked scanner (actually a multi-function printer/scanner HP Deskjet 2540) was no longer found by Simple Scan. I tried to put it back by installing hplip & hplip-gui but Simple Scan no longer found the the scanner. I noticed that the files above no longer existed. Any idea how to recover these files and thus (hopefully) make my scanner findable by Simple Scan again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it! I just had to reinstall HPLIP, go to the directory where the installer extracted all of the files, run `sudo make uninstall`, delete the files using the commands, restart my system, and it was done.

Answer (score 22):

Works for me:

```
cd /usr/share/hplip
sudo python uninstall.py
```

Comment: On newer setups `sudo python3 uninstall.py`

Comment: gave me an error "NameError: name 'get_distro_std_name' is not defined. Did you mean: 'get_distro_name'?"

Comment: @ColinD As of now you have to manually download and run the plugin